# How to make a real model of The Lego Batman Movie’s Kraken

Tags: design

I remember seeing The Lego Batman Movie in theaters with my dad in 2017, and it was one of my favorite movies of that year. It still is to this day. One thing that caught me off guard was the fact that the villains of the Phantom Zone were from other movies, such as Sauron from The Lord Of The Rings, Voldemort from Harry Potter, the shark from Jaws, Medusa from Lego Minifigures, the Wicked Witch and her Flying Monkeys from The Wizard Of Oz, The Daleks from Doctor Who, Agent Smith and his clones from The Matrix, the Gremlins, the T. Rex from Lego Dino Hunters, and the Velociraptors from Jurassic Park. My favorite Phantom Zone villian, though, has always been the Kraken from Clash Of The Titans (whom a lot of us mistook for Godzilla when the movie first came out) because he just has a sick design and is also the biggest character in the movie, consisting of 111,284 bricks according to a video I found on YouTube. I’ve always wished they made him into a real set.

However, I’ve looked online, and apparently, no one has ever tried to make their own Kraken, nor have they pitched the idea to Lego, which I want to do. It may be understandable as to why Lego hasn’t made this real. For one thing, it would have to be in a pretty big box, with three or four smaller boxes inside for different sections, like the colosseum set they released in 2020. For another, it’d cost a lot of money, and would take a long time to build. For another, it’d be a big build, so you’d had to have the space to display it. However, Lego has made sets of a similar size, like the Colosseum, the Hogwarts Castle, the Titanic, the World Map, the Super Mario Question Block, and the Millennium Falcon. But there is one question I have in mind. If I can’t get Lego to make this into an official set or find someone else to make it real for me, what kind of pieces would I need to make my own?

Let me start with the pieces I think or know for sure he is made from.

When the villains make their way to Wayne Manor, there is a shot of Joker riding the Kraken’s nose as he leads them there. In this shot, you can make out some of the pieces they used for the Kraken’s head.

https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/brickipedia/images/6/6a/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%BD2.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/1000?cb=20180519145817&path-prefix=ru

[image: Kraken]

As you can see from that photo, the main portion of his head appears to be made from 1x4 bricks, along with some 1x3s,2x2s, tall 1x2s,both thin and wide, tall 1x1s, 1x5s, and some 1x6s. As for plates, I can really only make out 1x4s and 2x2s. You can also see one big brick in front of his eye. I don’t know what to call that brick. If anyone knows the name of that particular piece, please let me know. It would really help me out. Speaking of his eyes, the Kraken’s eye is most definitely made of 1x1 bricks, especially around the pupil area, along with 1x2 bricks, 1x3 bricks, and 1x4 bricks.

The rest of his body is harder to tell. For his hand and arms, you can tell from the top and bottom that they used 2x4s. His teeth are probably tall 1x1s and 1x2s. I thought they were made of some 2x2s, but now I’m not so sure. In this shot of the Kraken and King Kong tearing a building the gang is hiding in, that is one of the few full body shots of him you can see in the movie.

https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/brickipedia/images/6/68/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%BD3.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/1000?cb=20180519145837&path-prefix=ru

[image: Kraken]

It’s not that good, and yes, there are slightly better pictures, but I don’t want to wast time finding them. You can watch the movie to look for them.

The Kraken’s lower body I’m guessing is made of 2x2x3s, with a few 1x4s and 1x5s here and there. A single giant stud in the center connects his torso to his lower body. His head is most likely connected with a brick built version of a typical Lego Minifigure neck.  I can’t tell what pieces make up the stud.

A few final questions I have.

What pieces would be best for his arm and tail joints, especially since he has three more joints than an average Lego minifigure?

How to make sure the holes are the right size to fit his arms without them falling out or being too loose?

How to size up his torso and lower body correctly?

Would it be more effective to make his torso hollow or put a single hole to attach his torso to his lower body?

If the jaw and eyes were to move like the movie, how would the mechanism work?

What would be the way to build his frills, spikes, fins and tongue?

If some of the pieces I need for the Kraken don’t exist in that color or are very hard to come by, what is the solution?

Sorry if I made this so long. It’s just that I’d give anything to have a real model of the Kraken, so if I got someone to make it for me, I’d want them to make it look like the movie as much as possible. If someone has any pointers, tips, or suggestions, They are way more than welcomed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Hernandez and welcome to Bricks.SE! I see many questions in your post, most of which are way too subjective ("Should I...?", "How would...?"), therefore as of now, this post is a poor fit for this platform. See the [tour] and [help] pages for more, but nevertheless, please try to rework the question to focus on a single, objectively answerable question.

Comment: The large brick you're talking about looks like the back side of [part 59349 - Panel 1 x 6 x 5](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=59349#T=S&C=6&O={%22color%22:6,%22iconly%22:0}) in green. Possibly also [part 3754 - Brick 1 x 6 x 5](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3754#T=C) though it never came in green.